# Anaconda files in 2 different drives? HELP Anaconda + Jupyter notebook not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have two drives on my computer, a C and a D drive. I have installed all my anaconda files on the D drive but I cannot open Jupyter notebook. It seems that Anaconda is trying to import files from the C drive and returns traceback errors.
How can I fix this?

I deleted all anaconda files from the C drive but it did not work.

```
(base) C:\Users\YEV>jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:\DataScience\Anaconda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DataScience\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

I just want to be able to run anaconda and Jupyter notebook.

Now I understand some of the files are in the C drive and some in the D drive. Not sure why. How can I fix it please?

```
(base) C:\Users\YEV>jupyter --paths
config:
    C:\Users\YEV\.jupyter
    D:\DataScience\Anaconda\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    D:\DataScience\Anaconda\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\Users\YEV\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

Thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using, which drive is your OS running on, which drive contains your user/home folder and system path?

Comment: Windows 10, OS running in C drive, user/home folder in C drive. I installed all else in D drive. Is that why I have this issue? My C drive is almost full so I thought I would install Anaconda on D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, anaconda install itself and python packages (via pip?) in $Users$ directory.

If you delete them, your packages will be gone.

I suggest you re-install anaconda from scratch.

Comment: I did that twice, but for some reason some files still get installed on the C drive although I specified the D drive path. How can I change the location of the config file?

Comment: Are you using conda env ? How did you install jupyter ? It is not anaconda's fault I think. It's more jupyter set-up problem.

Comment: Are you installing jupyter with pip or with conda? Installing with conda should place it in whichever environment you're using